# More fancy way to deal with selecting non-existing records to avoid null exception errors

Tags: c#, mysql

It was bugging me, why neither of `??` or `== null` works when I want to select a record that doesn't exist. For example if I do

```
var foo = db.Where(k => k.ID == 9) ?? bar;
```

it works fine, but it crashes (`Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error) when I want to `select` single field:

```
var foo = db.Where(k => k.ID == 9).Select(k => k.Field).FirstOrDefault() ?? bar;
//or
var foo = bar;
if (db.Where(k => k.ID == 9) != null)
    foo = db.Where(k => k.ID == 9).Select(k => k.Field).FirstOrDefault()
```

In both cases It crashes, which seems to be pretty logical.

Normally I wouldn't mind doing

```
if (Order.A_Data.Where(k => k.FieldID == 9).Count() > 0)
    writeText(cb, Order.A_Data.Where(k => k.FieldID == 9).
        Select(k => k.Content).
        FirstOrDefault().ToString(), 
    left_margin, top_margin - 24, f_cn, 10);
    //this looks more like the actual code, but in fact it has multiple 'where' conditions and more tables connected with an external key, that's why I don't want to write the same thing over and over again
    //or creating new variables
```

but sadly I have to re-create really complicated PDF document with literally hundreds of fields* like these obtaining data from dozens of tables, so every "trickier way" will be very helpfull. Also, it's very slow.

*Or maybe there is a keep-your-null-exception-errors-for-yourself-and-just-return-an-empty-string switch?*

---

**278 to be more specific. So I can either find easy way to do this, or prepare another bucket of coffee, sigh and do my job*

Comment: Where does the error actually happen? As far as I know, `db.Where(k => k.ID == 9)` should never return `null`, right?

Comment: What is the data type of `k.Field` ?

Comment: @JuliánUrbano - Visual Studio shows me `NullReferenceException was unhandled bu user code ...` when I try to generate the document

Comment: @Andomar nullable `nvchar`

Comment: @PabloLemurr maybe your `db` variable is null?. That `where` shouldn't return null. Try debugging and see where the exception actually occurs.

Comment: @JuliánUrbano - it is definetely not ;) (In fact, it's just a database context object) When I have opened contents of the table I can see that there is actually no records that matches `where`

Comment: @PabloLemurr Also take a look at `db.SingleOrDefault(k => k.ID=9)` instead of `Where` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use:

```
var foo = db.Where(k => k.ID == 9).FirstOrDefault().Field;
```

That should return a default object with `null` properties if it didn't find a row.

**Edit** Now I understand. You want something like this:

```
var foo = db.Where(k => k.ID == 9).DefaultIfEmpty(bar).First().Field;
```

Comment: Doesn't `FirstOrDefault()` just return `null` for an empty set?  [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx): "The default value for reference and nullable types is null."

Comment: I thought that's what OP was looking for? He's trying to `null-coalesce` the field. Perhaps I didn't understand correctly.

Comment: In your answer, wouldn't `null.Field` throw an exception?

Comment: What is the use of accessing the `Field` of a new instance when there is no ID=9? Most probably that is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Correct, just noticed OP was coalescing with `bar`. Edit now reflects that.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your edit, a database `nvarchar` usually maps to a `String`, a reference type.

But when a database `nvarchar` is `null`, it returns `DBNull.Value` to the .NET client instead of `null`.  (Must be the most confusing thing in all of .NET.)

Try:

```
var foo = bar;
var row = db.FirstOrDefault(k => k.ID == 9);
if (row != null && row.Field != DBNull.Value)
    foo = row.Field;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be here

```
if (Order.A_Data.Where(k => k.FieldID == 9).Count() > 0)
    writeText(cb, Order.A_Data.Where(k => k.FieldID == 9).
        Select(k => k.Content).
        FirstOrDefault().ToString(), 
    left_margin, top_margin - 24, f_cn, 10);
```

You select where `ID=9`, take only the `Content` and then `FirstOrDefault`. So far so good, if there is a match you get the order. But if there is no match the `FirstOrDefault` will return null and therefore the `ToString` will throw an exception. Try this:

```
var order = Order.A_Data.SingleOrDefault(k => k.FieldID == 9); // Get the order
if(order != null){ // and check if we have a match
    writeText(cb, order.Content.ToString(), // write the Content of the match
    left_margin, top_margin - 24, f_cn, 10);
}else{
    // handle however you want when there are no orders matching
}
```

Note that I'm using `SingleOrDefault` instead of `FirstOrDefault`. This is because I'm assuming you will only have one order with `FieldID` equal to 9. If you can have more, use `FirstOrDefault` instead.

Comment: Why `SingleOrDefault` instead of `FirstOrDefault` ?  The "single" variant throws an exception when multiple elements match.

Comment: Seems he's selecting by order ID, so there should only be one. I added a short comment at the end anyway